# Unload me or formname.hide doesnt work excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

In excel-vba i have a form named `frmTemplateSelector` when I select one of the two options and click on "done", the form doesn't hide!

I am calling `frm.show` from another module, where in depending on choice, other pop ups will appear.

```
Private Sub btnDone_Click()
    frmTemplateSelector.Hide
    Exit Sub
End Sub
Private Sub btn1_Click()
    name = "XYZ"
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click()
    name = "ABC"
End Sub
```

Comment: `Me.Hide` works for me. Can you show us the code of the other module calling the form, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can either `Unload` or `Hide` an UserForm.

**Hide** literally only hide the UF

**Unload** hide and reset all variables in the UF

```
Private Sub btnDone_Click()
    Unload frmTemplateSelector 'or Unload Me
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

You can also change the UF's name to `Me` in this code, as it is the UF's code module, like this :

```
Private Sub btnDone_Click()
    Me.Hide
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @R3uK and Brno But its inconsistent. It works in first go but next time onwards it doesnt, I have even added "Application.screenUpdating = True

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? The UF is still on top of screen after using the button to close? You can add `Unload Me` in the `UserForm_Terminate` event, that might help.

Comment: Ok I will try the _terminate or _Exit. Currently it stays on top of screen and pops up another MsgBox which I am calling after this hide.